# MS ExchangeService - get custom calendar (OR calendars list)

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Using `ExchangeService` I need to get Calendar folder and retrieve all events there
It's done by this piece of code

```
 private List getRoomCalendar() throws Exception {
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.setUrl(new URI(msExchangeUrl));
    FolderView fv = new FolderView(100);
    fv.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);
    FolderId confRoomFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(username));
    System.out.println(confRoomFolderId.getFolderName());
    List events = new ArrayList();

    Date date = new Date();

    try {
        CalendarFolder calendarFolder = CalendarFolder.bind(service, confRoomFolderId);
        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(new DateTime(date).minusDays(1).toDate(),
                new DateTime(date).plusDays(1).toDate(), 100);
        cView.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject,
                AppointmentSchema.Start,
                AppointmentSchema.End));
        // we can set other properties as well depending upon our need.
        FindItemsResults appointments = calendarFolder.findAppointments(cView);
        List<Appointment> appList = appointments.getItems();
        for (Appointment appointment : appList) {
            Map event = readEvent(appointment);
            events.add(event);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return events;
}

private Map readEvent(Appointment appointment) {
    Map appointmentData = new HashMap();
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        appointmentData.put("appointmentSubject", appointment.getSubject());
        appointmentData.put("appointmentStartTime", df.format(appointment.getStart()));
        appointmentData.put("appointmentEndTime", df.format(appointment.getEnd()));
    } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return appointmentData;
}
```

Cool, it's working and returns these data

[default MS Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AZgk.jpg)

The question is: how can I get events for MY CUSTOM CALENDAR called `name`
see here

[custom MS calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwgiW.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to create the folderView first. Afterwards, apply a search filter, find it using FindFolderResults.

```
PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(1);
fvFolderView.setPropertySet(psPropset);
SearchFilter SfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName,"name");
FindFoldersResults findFoldersResults = service.findFolders(confRoomFolderId, SfSearchFilter, fvFolderView); 
System.out.println(findFoldersResults.getFolders().get(0).getDisplayName());
```